# Build failed apk with AdMobPro

Tags: ionic2, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

i detect the problem is with AdMobPro plugin

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro
>
> cordova build android

stacktrace

> cordova build android
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Yassine\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 Subproject Path:
>   CordovaLib The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
>   Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>           at build_axxz9tj19izrj5q0qkz0lbpfl.run(F:\test1\platforms\android\build.gradle:137)
>   The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Incremental java compilation
>   is an incubating feature. The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please
>   use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :checkDebugManifest
>   :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileLint
>   :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig :CordovaLib:processDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
>   :CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g.
>   outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.). Note: Some input
>   files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:bundleDebug :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
>   :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g.
>   outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.). Note: Some input
>   files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:bundleRelease
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1104Library
>   :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
>   :prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib623DebugLibrary
>   :prepareDebugDependencies :compileDebugAidl :compileDebugRenderscript
>   :generateDebugBuildConfig :generateDebugResValues
>   :generateDebugResources :mergeDebugResources Error: Failed to crunch
>   file
>   F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png into
>   F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png :mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Error: Failed to crunch file F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png into
>   >     F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 21.484 secs Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input
>   files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Error: Failed to crunch file F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png into
>   >     F:\test1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

if i remove this plugin admobpro and build it is work